# VirtualBox does not boot hybrid GPT/MBR, neither EFI nor MBR

Tags: boot, virtualbox, grub, mbr, gpt

The same version of VirtualBox on the same installed Debian system does not boot from the raw disk USB flash drive, while on the other system it does, it is also possible to boot the USB flash drive connected to a physical machine.

It is a USB with GPT protective MBR partitioning. Booting both in WFI mode and in legacy MBR mode works perfectly and GRUB starts without problems.

In a VirtualBox installation I can't start the UEFI bootloader, it remains empty even when executing grubx64.efi directly and in mbr mode it starts grub but the operating system boot remains empty.

In MBR mode I can load the kernel from GRUB, but after the boot command the virtual machine hangs.

There are no adapters, it is the usb directly converted to a virtual medium in mode:

```
VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /home/n7rc/VirtualBox\ VMs/sda.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda
```

Log the machine right up to the crash

```
00:00:01.159174 Console: Machine state changed to 'Running'
00:00:01.159174 GUI: Capturing keyboard on resume
00:00:01.158119 HM: fUsePauseFilter=false fUseLbrVirt=false fUseVGif=true  fUseVirtVmsaveVmload=true 
00:00:01.164758 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: VirtualBox 6.1.32
00:00:01.164860 PCI: Setting up resources and interrupts
00:00:01.165587 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:01.190806 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:01.190941 VMMDev: Guest Log: CPUID EDX: 0x178bfbff
00:00:01.190976 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0x00 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0x00 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:01.191007 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:01.191336 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: ata0-0: PCHS=16383/16/63 LCHS=1024/255/63
00:00:01.193345 PIT: mode=2 count=0x48d3 (18643) - 64.00 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:01.220491 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=00007f8b71400000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:01.664006 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::resendSizeHint: Restoring guest size-hint for screen 0 to 800x600
00:00:01.667309 GUI: 2D video acceleration is disabled
00:00:01.667515 GUI: HID LEDs sync is not supported on this platform
00:00:01.683725 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:03.677023 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:03.683627 PIT: mode=2 count=0x10000 (65536) - 18.20 Hz (ch=0)
00:00:03.684020 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Boot : bseqnr=1, bootseq=0002
00:00:03.684510 VMMDev: Guest Log: BIOS: Booting from Hard Disk...
00:00:03.685146 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: RESET, DevSel=0 AIOIf=0 CmdIf0=0xc4 (-1 usec ago) CmdIf1=0xa1 (-1 usec ago)
00:00:03.685222 PIIX3 ATA: Ctl#0: finished processing RESET
00:00:03.848601 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=00007f8b7152c000 w=640 h=480 bpp=32 cbLine=0xA00 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:27.686597 Display::i_handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=0000000000000000 w=720 h=400 bpp=0 cbLine=0x0 flags=0x0 origin=0,0
00:00:31.709861 GUI: Machine-window #0 deactivated
00:00:31.709926 GUI: Releasing mouse on focus out
00:00:31.709935 GUI: Releasing keyboard on focus out
00:00:31.710628 GUI: Machine-view #0 unfocused, reason=3
```

[image]

Comment: How is the disk _physically_ connected to the machine? Are USB adapters involved somehow?

Comment: There are no adapters, it is the usb directly converted to a virtual medium in mode: VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /home/n7rc/VirtualBox\ VMs/sda.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/sda

Comment: @n7rc - You should edit and update your question

Comment: Selecting an AHCI controller for the virtual disk originating from the physical USB was solved.

Comment: Please do not [edit your question to declare “Solved.”](https://superuser.com/posts/1703861/revisions) That is not how this community works. If you have self-solved a question, please just post your own answer and then check it off as the answer. This is an acceptable way to self-solve an issue. So if the answer is “Selecting an AHCI controller for the virtual disk originating from the physical USB was solved.” then just post that as an answer and check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting an AHCI controller for the virtual disk originating from the physical USB was solved.